# How can I use WaitHandle awaiting completion of an asynchronous call?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, begininvoke, waithandle, waitone

Consider this code:

```
class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Master master = new Master();
                master.Execute();
            }
        }

    class TestClass
    {
        public void Method(string s)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            Console.WriteLine("End Method()");
        }
    }
    class Master
    {
        private readonly TestClass test = new TestClass();

        public void Execute()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Start main thread..");
            Action<String> act = test.Method;
            IAsyncResult res = act.BeginInvoke("Start Method()..", x =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Start Callback..");
                act.EndInvoke(x);
                Console.WriteLine("End Callback");
            }, null);
            Console.WriteLine("End main thread");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

We have result:

```
Start main thread..
End main thread
Start Method()..
End Method()
Start Callback..
End Callback
```

So, I want result:

```
Start main thread..    
Start Method()..
End Method()
Start Callback..
End Callback
End main thread
```

How can I wait `async` in this code? I checked MSDN article ["Calling Synchronous Methods Asynchronously"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e08f6yc.aspx) and found this:

After calling `BeginInvoke` you can do the following:

- Do some work and then call `EndInvoke` to block until the call
  completes.
- Obtain a `WaitHandle` using the `IAsyncResultAsyncWaitHandle`
  property, use its `WaitOne` method to block execution until the
  `WaitHandle` is signaled, and then call `EndInvoke`.
- Poll the    `IAsyncResult` returned by `BeginInvoke` to determine when
  the    asynchronous call has completed, and then call `EndInvoke`.
- Pass a    delegate for a callback method to `BeginInvoke`. The method
  is executed    on a `ThreadPool` thread when the asynchronous call
  completes. The    callback method calls `EndInvoke`.

I think better variant for me this second. But how implement this? In particular I'm interested overload `WaitOne()` ([Blocks the current thread until the current WaitHandle receives a signal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.threading.waithandle.waitone.aspx)). How correctly do it? I mean the common pattern in this case.

**UPDATE:**

Now I use `Task<T>`:

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Master master = new Master();
            master.Execute();
        }
    }

    class WebService
    {
        public int GetResponse(int i)
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            i = i + rand.Next();
            Console.WriteLine("Start GetResponse()");
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            Console.WriteLine("End GetResponse()");
            return i;
        }

        public void SomeMethod(List<int> list)
        {
            //Some work with list        
            Console.WriteLine("List.Count = {0}", list.Count);
        }
    }
    class Master
    {
        private readonly WebService webService = new WebService();

        public void Execute()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Start main thread..");
            List<int> listResponse = new List<int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                var task = Task<int>.Factory.StartNew(() => webService.GetResponse(1))
                    .ContinueWith(x =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Start Callback..");
                        listResponse.Add(x.Result);
                        Console.WriteLine("End Callback");
                    });
            }
            webService.SomeMethod(listResponse);
            Console.WriteLine("End main thread..");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Main problem this is `SomeMethod()` gets empty `list`.

Result:
[image]

Now I have monstrous solution :(

```
 public void Execute()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Start main thread..");
            List<int> listResponse = new List<int>();
            int count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                var task = Task<int>.Factory.StartNew(() => webService.GetResponse(1))
                    .ContinueWith(x =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Start Callback..");
                        listResponse.Add(x.Result);
                        Console.WriteLine("End Callback");
                        count++;
                        if (count == 5)
                        {
                            webService.SomeMethod(listResponse);
                        }
                    });

            }
            Console.WriteLine("End main thread..");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Result:

[image]

That's what I need to wait for the asynchronous call. How can I use `Wait` for `Task` here?

**UPDATE 2:**

```
class Master
{
    private readonly WebService webService = new WebService();
    public delegate int GetResponseDelegate(int i);

    public void Execute()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Start main thread..");
        GetResponseDelegate act = webService.GetResponse;
        List<int> listRequests = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            act.BeginInvoke(1, (result =>
            {                    
                int req = act.EndInvoke(result);
                listRequests.Add(req);
            }), null);  
        }

        webService.SomeMethod(listRequests);
        Console.WriteLine("End main thread..");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that is what you want. We are starting tasks and then waiting them to complete, after all are completed, we are getting results.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Master master = new Master();
        master.Execute();
    }
}

class WebService
{
    public int GetResponse(int i)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        i = i + rand.Next();
        Console.WriteLine("Start GetResponse()");
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        Console.WriteLine("End GetResponse()");
        return i;
    }

    public void SomeMethod(List<int> list)
    {
        //Some work with list        
        Console.WriteLine("List.Count = {0}", list.Count);
    }
}
class Master
{
    private readonly WebService webService = new WebService();
    public void Execute()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Start main thread..");
        var taskList = new List<Task<int>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Task<int> task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => webService.GetResponse(1));
            taskList.Add(task);
        }

        Task<List<int>> continueWhenAll =
            Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(taskList.ToArray(),
                            tasks => tasks.Select(task => task.Result).ToList());

        webService.SomeMethod(continueWhenAll.Result);
        Console.WriteLine("End main thread..");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

}
```

**Ugly solution with BeginIvoke/EndInvoke**

```
public void Execute()
{
    Func<int, int> func = webService.GetResponce;

    var countdownEvent = new CountdownEvent(5);
    var res = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        func.BeginInvoke(1, ar =>
                        {
                            var asyncDelegate = (Func<int, int>)((AsyncResult)ar).AsyncDelegate;
                            int ii = asyncDelegate.EndInvoke(ar);
                            res.Add(ii);
                            ((CountdownEvent)((AsyncResult)ar).AsyncState).Signal();
                        }, countdownEvent);
    }
    countdownEvent.Wait();
    Console.WriteLine(res.Count);
}
```

Comment: Hamlet, could you please check my update 2 in post? I'm interested in academic purposes, if use async BeginInvoke() is it possible to achieve the same result as in your reply?

Answer (score 1):

From your sample code it is not clear why you need async invocation. If you don't, you can just call `test.Method();` synchronously.

Assuming that you need async execution, don't bother with the obsolete `Delegate.BeginInvoke` stuff. Use the new `Task`-based API:

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => test.Method());
```

You can then `Wait` on the task or `await` it or use `Task.ContinueWith` (choose the appropriate technique for your case).

Comment: Usr, thank for feedback! Really, I gave bad samples code. I work with Windows Phone 7.5 and async requests to web-service. In samples code I hide this moment, because I want simple code in example. Update for my post has most similar to reality code. And I use Task-based API, it's available in Windows Phone 7 :)

Comment: That's an entirely different question now... It looks like you need a good tutorial on how concurrency works. You code is not safe and could benefit from a few best-practices. I recommend picking up the basics using tutorial material.